How can I improve copy times between an Android phone and my home computer
How can I improve copy times between an Android phone and my home computer.
It is a USB3 port which has faster transfer speeds than the USB 2.0 that is on the right side of my desktop computer. Direct cable from the smart phone to a USB 3 port. I do NOT use WiFi.
Thunar is my file manager.
Transferring 1.5 Gb of data in the form of pictures and videos takes around 45 minutes using the Copy command.
I am using U_Mate 24.04.
Galaxy A25 5G
Android Version 14


Please identify how you are transferring, if over a USB cable what is the Android device USB speed / PC USB speed, if over WiFi provide details. Regardless, identifying the Android device model and OS version may be helpful.

If you search for "USB file transfer speeds on Linux" you'll find quite a bit. Just looking at the PC I can't tell if the front USB panel even supports USB 2.0 standard, you'll have to check you PC's Linux log messages. You would also have to check if the back USB ports are different. It may help to know if both the PC and Android phone are connected to the same WiFi, i.e. if PC has a ethernet connection to WiFi router, you may have better speeds from the phone to your PC via FTP/SFTP over WiFi (a Gig of data will still take time).

Already a SD-card reader might be a bottleneck if not USB3.x, and flash memory is slow in general - the phone's internal flash might not be a speedy type, and e.g. a uSD card might also set limits. I'd say that a proper USB 3.x card reader combined with suitable flash-memory media might be the quickest. Assuming your phone has a slot for that media.

It is a USB3 port. I am not using a SD card. Direct cable from the smart phone to a USB 3 port. I do NOT use WiFi.

The phone has an USB-C port however according to Samsung it supports only USB 2.0 which means you are limited to ~30MB/sec for large files. Smaller files will be transferred slower because of general overhead. And I would try to use adb instead of MTP or one of the other "consumer protocols" that is most likely used by your file-manager on PC side.

@Robert Can you provide an actual example of "adb instead of MTP or one of the other "consumer protocols" that is most likely used by your file-manager on PC side." Thanks.

What do you mean by "actual example"? Just try it out yourself. Enable Developer Mode and adb on the phone and install adb e.g. via your Linux packagemanager. Adb is a pure command-line use it via adb pull / adb push.

@Robert I have a developer settings, but it has nothing that I see for "Enabling Developer Mode." I see Version 14.1.00.6.

developer settings is what I call developer mode. Then just enable adb (Android Debug Bridge)

@Robert I appreciate your attempt to help me. I will post my question on other sites who may have a better understanding of what help I am seeking.
